# SQL RegEx Create Split: Include SET

Tags: mysql, regex

I'm writing a regex pattern to split MySQL `CREATE` statements into column definition arrays. So far, it works great for everything aside from `SET` columns.  Here's the process:

```
$lines = explode("\n", $create_sql);

foreach ($lines as $line) {
    $line = str_replace('NOT NULL', 'NOT_NULL', $line);

    $pattern = '/`(.*)`[\s]*([^\s]*)[\s]*(NOT_NULL|NULL)[\s]*(.*),/';

    $search = preg_match($pattern, $line, $matches);

    if ($search !== false && count($matches) === 5) {
        $columns[$matches[1]] = array(
            'type' => $matches[2],
            'null' => $matches[3] === 'NULL',
            'extra' => $matches[4],
        );
    }
}
```

This process works great on a column with a definition like this:

```
`id`          INT(11)               NOT NULL         AUTO_INCREMENT,
```

...but fails on `SET` columns. How can I best accommodate for the extra quotes and parentheses in this line?

```
`platform`    SET('iOS', 'Android') NULL             DEFAULT NULL,
```

---

**To summarize**, I need to integrate a pattern to match `SET('one', 'two', n)` in a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First just let slightly modify your pattern expression, first for readability (`\s*` instead of `[\s]*`), then to ensure working even with lowercase statements :

```
$pattern = '/`(.*)`\s*([^\s]*)\s*(NOT_NULL|NULL)\s*(.*),/i';
```

Then, to answer your question, prepare the pattern depending on a `SET` is present or not in the line:

```
$sub_pattern = stripos($line, ' SET(') ?
  'SET\([^\)]*\)\s*[^\s]*' 
  : '[^\s]*';
$pattern = '/`(.*)`\s*(' . $sub_pattern . ')\s*(NOT_NULL|NULL)\s*(.*),/i';
```

Note that, however, this code is not secured against syntax errors in the source lines.

Comment: Thanks @cFreed. Great idea to look for the exception with PHP; is there any way you can see to do the if/then `$sub_pattern` check directly in the regex?

Comment: @jterry It's what I spontaneously considered before posting my answer, and the intuitive way for that is to merely include the two cases as an alternative in the pattern: `'/`(.*)`\s*(SET\([^\)]*\)\s*[^\s]*|[^\s]*)\s*(NOT_NULL|NULL)\s*(.*),/i'`. But it needs to be finely analyzed to be sure there are no unexpected side effects. It's why I preferred to suggest a more secure way.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Input: $sql
$match = '(
             ([^(),]+?|       # no parens, or contains ():
              [^(),]+?
            \(  [^)]+?  \)  # (123), (enum...), etc
              [^(),]*?
           )  \s*(,\s*|$)           # separator or terminator
         )';

preg_match('/(CREATE\s+TABLE.*?\()(.*)(\)[^()]*(;|$))/si', $sql, $m);
list($x, $pre, $list, $post, $z) = $m;
$list = trim($list);
$list = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $list);
$list = preg_replace("/$match/sx", "$1
    ", $list);
$list = trim($list);

// Output:
echo "<pre>
$pre
    $list
$post\n</pre>\n";
```

Notes:

- Certain quoted strings will fail to parse correctly.
- I think all cases of parentheses work ok.
- You will still need to parse each element in $list[], which should be one per column.